# How to select next or previous item in a drop down menu with Imacros?

Tags: drop-down-menu, imacros

We have a drop down menu, and it always has a selected item let's say 'elem1'.
My goal is to select the next item to 'elem1', and with another execution of the code we select the next one, and so on.

example:

```
    <select>
         <option >elem1</option>
         <option >elem2</option>
         <option >elem3</option>
         <option >elem4</option>
         <option >elem5</option>
         <option >elem6</option>
         <option >elem7</option>
    </select>
```

at first 'elem1' is selected.

```
first  execution result ==> 'elem2' = selected
second execution result ==> 'elem3' = selected
third  execution result ==> 'elem4' = selected
```

and so on...(the same thing for previous selection).

Answer (score 0):

for this you can use relative position like below

```
TAG POS=1 TYPE=option ATTR=TXT:elem2
TAG POS=R1 TYPE=option ATTR=TXT:*
```